# Closure in Stone-Cech

Tags: general-topology

Supose X is a discrete topological space, and consider $\beta(X)\times \beta(X)$. We can see $X \times X \subset \beta(X)\times \beta(X)$. Given $A,B \subseteq X \times X$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Is it true that $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$?.

Comment: It's not true that $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$, BTW. $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$ does hold, I agree with @user87690 .

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the intersection lies in $X×X$ because of $B$. But $\overline{A}^{βX×βX} ∩ (X×X) = \overline{A}^{X×X} = A$. The last equality holds because $X×X$ is discrete.

Comment: Thanks! Now i see.

Comment: In not so few words,  $\bar A \cap B=\bar A \cap (X^2\cap B)=(\bar A \cap X^2)\cap B=Cl_{X^2}(A)\cap B=A\cap B.$