# Stone-Cech compactification and discrete space

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Suppose $X$ is a discrete space and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subspaces of $X$.

Then consider $\beta(X) \times \beta(X)$,
We can think of $A \times A, B \times B$ as a subspace of $ \beta(X) \times \beta(X)$, where $\beta(X)$ is Stone-Cech compactification of $X$.

Then it’s not true that $\overline{A \times A} \cap \overline{B \times B}$ is empty. So $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ is non-empty.

But in Munkres’ Introduction to topology,

There’s an exercise which says that

> If $X$ is discrete space and $A$ is a subspace of $X$, then show that $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{X \setminus A}$ are disjoint.

It seems to me that those are contradicting to each other. Is there any missing point I couldn’t see? Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say $\overline{A \times A} \cap \overline{B \times B}$ is nonempty?

Comment: @EricWofsey I read a comment in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2331076/406325 am I miss-reading?

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then so are $A \times A$ and $B \times B$.  Then this is the case discussed in the thread. Isn't it?

Comment: When that comment says "It's not true..." it means "It's not _necessarily_ true" (i.e., the universally quantified statement is not true).  Obviously there are some examples when it is true (e.g., if both sets are empty).

Comment: @EricWofsey Ahha, then if $B$ is choosen as $X \setminus A$, then they have to be disjoint?

Comment: No, not in general.  But it is true when you have disjoint sets of the form $A\times A$ and $B\times B$.

Comment: You seem to be getting two quite different situations confused--one where you are considering the closures of subsets of $X$ in $\beta X$ and one where you are considering the closures of subsets of $X\times X$ in $\beta X\times \beta X$.

Comment: So is it $\beta X \times \beta X \ne \beta(X\times X)$?

Comment: Yes, they are quite different (when $X$ is infinite).

Comment: @EricWofsey Is there any example I can manipulate easily?

Comment: Well, for instance, if $D=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ and $u\in\beta X\setminus X$ then $(u,u)$ is in the closure of both $D$ and $X\times X\setminus D$ in $\beta X\times \beta X$, since every neighborhood of $u$ in $\beta X$ contains more than one point of $X$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see it now. Thank you, it really helped me.

Comment: @glimpser Then you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closures are taken in the (product of) compactification, not in the original $X$. And the compactification **is not** discrete. Hence no contradiction with Munkres.

The fundamental reason is that if $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$ then the closure of $A$ in $B$ need not be equal the closure of $A$ in $C$. In fact the latter may be bigger. To visualize this consider $X=\{0, 1\}$ with the antidiscrete topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$ and $A=B=\{0\}$. Note that $A,B$ are discrete and so the closure of $A$ in $B$ is just $A$. But the closure of $A$ in $X$ is whole $X$.

The situation when the intermediate closure is equal to the outer closure is when the middle subspace $B$ is closed in $X$. In your situation that would require $X$ to be closed in $\beta(X)$ and this can only happen when $X$ is compact to begin with (and so it is equal to its own Stone-Cech compactification).